# Show Upsell products of a product in category group wise

Tags: magento

I want to fetch upsell products and display it in my homepage 
and i had used the following code

```
$sku=$this->getRequest()->getParam('subvalue');
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);

$related_product_collection = $_product->getUpSellProductCollection()`;
```

Now I want to categorize the upsell products..As in i want to fetch and display products of different categories differently...Like headphones from upsell products should be displayed differently and Bluetooth devices from from upsell products should be displayed differently...Please help

Comment: do you mean you want to show upsell products like this:
Category headphones: product headphone1, product headphone2
Category bluetooth: product bluetooth1, product bluetooth2 
right?

Comment: yup. exactly
products belonging to headphone category in upsell products and products belonging to bluetooth category in upsell products should be displyed difrntly